# Disable CI/CD in gitlab using helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I have installed Gitlab using Helm chart and I want to disable CI/CD option, it should be disabled on UI as well.
Was not able to find any documentation to do it using helm charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this document , I was able to disable CICD.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/enable_or_disable_ci.html

```
## Default project features settings
default_projects_features:
  issues: true
  merge_requests: true
  wiki: true
  snippets: false
  builds: false
```

By setting builds to false in helm chart we can disable CICD.

Two things to note:

- Disabling GitLab CI/CD, will affect only newly-created projects.
  Projects that had it enabled prior to this modification, will work as
  before.
- Even if you disable GitLab CI/CD, users will still be able to enable
  it in the project’s settings.